# Pure js add and remove (toggle) class after scrolling x amount?

Tags: javascript

I don't want to use jQuery for this.

It's really simple, I just want to add a class after scrolling past a certain amount of pixels (lets say 10px) and remove it if we ever go back to the top 10 pixels.

My best attempt was:

```
var scrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
var header = document.getElementById("header");

function add_class_on_scroll() {
    header.classList.add("fade-in");
}

function remove_class_on_scroll() {
    header.classList.remove("fade-in");
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if(scrollpos > 10){
        add_class_on_scroll();
    }
    else {
        remove_class_on_scroll();
    }
    console.log(scrollpos);
});
```

But console shows a number that continues to grow regardless of scrolling up or down. And the class `fade-in` never gets added, though console shows we past 10.

Comment: Could you post the code to `jsfiddle.net` or `jsbin.com` so that it would be easier to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot to change the offset value in the scroll handler.

```
//use window.scrollY
var scrollpos = window.scrollY;
var header = document.getElementById("header");

function add_class_on_scroll() {
    header.classList.add("fade-in");
}

function remove_class_on_scroll() {
    header.classList.remove("fade-in");
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ 
    //Here you forgot to update the value
    scrollpos = window.scrollY;

    if(scrollpos > 10){
        add_class_on_scroll();
    }
    else {
        remove_class_on_scroll();
    }
    console.log(scrollpos);
});
```

Now you code works properly

### Explanation

There is no documentation for that, like you asked for. This is just an issue in the logic workflow.

When you say that `scrollpos = window.scrollY` your page is at an top-offset of 0, so your variable stores that value.
When the page scrolls, your `scroll` listener will fires. When yout listener checks for the `scrollpos` value, the value is still `0`, of course.
But if, at every scroll handler, you update the `scrollpos` value, now you can have a dynamic value.

Another option is you to create a getter, like

```
var scrollpos = function(){return window.scrollY};
```

This way you can dynamically check what that method will return for you at every offset.

```
if(scrollpos() > 10)
```

See? Hope that helped. (:

Comment: Thank You!!!! So I just needed to define or redefine the variable inside the Scroll event listener? I thought it would work fine if I defined it outside of the function. Can someone kindly reference me some documentation on whatever this may be called? I'd like to learn more.

Comment: No problem, i'll edit the answer with more details. (:

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! Makes total sense now.

Comment: for better cross browser support replace scrollY with pageYOffset see [pageYOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to achieve what you want (one line of code inside the `scroll` event):

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('header').classList[e.pageY > 10 ? 'add' : 'remove']('fade-in');
});
```

```css
#header {
  height: 600px;
}

.fade-in {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id='header'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the method toggle in `classList`

```
header.classList.toggle('fade-in')
```

Comment: and if want less jquery, I love this repo, can be helpful https://github.com/oneuijs/You-Dont-Need-jQuery